# Change select color once an option has been selected

Tags: css

I'm trying to change the css color of a select box once an option has been selected. Seems like it would be easy and common but I can't seem to find an answer.

Basically, I am starting out with a dimmed color (#999) on the select and then once the user selects an option it should change to #222 (think of the first option as placeholder text). I'm sure most people will say I need to apply the color to the option but I have tried that and it only works for the options themselves and not the starting color for the box. I've tried javascript and again, it works for the options themselves but not the select color.

Comment: Can you post your code please ?

Comment: ^not in a way that would make sense, its all fragmented in MVC

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with JQuery.  Make a before and after class that looks the way you want. Then switch after the click

```
$('#Mycontrol').click(function(){
    $('#Mycontrol').addClass('MynewClass');
});
```

Comment: Thanks this will work fine. Not sure why I didn't think of it.